# Haskell - Errors when declaring types

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn Haskell from the wikiBooks pages and there was this example code

```
pts :: Int -> Int
pts 1 = 10
pts 2 = 6
pts x
    | x <= 6    = 7 - x
    | otherwise = 0
```

When I put in the first line I get this error:
:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: pts :: Int -> Int
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the interactive shell `ghci`?

Comment: Yeah in that console screen ghci

Comment: then it is a duplicate, see the reference.

Comment: Okay, I will do that